# Failed cat an opened txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that captures the output of a binary into a .txt file, and then read the text file and send an email to me:

```
while :
do
# Start tunneling
#url=$(lt --port 8080 &) 
lt --port 8080 > url_info.txt &

url=$(cat url_info.txt)

# Send Email
./send.sh "$url" &

wait
done
```

After debugging for a while, it seems like the line of `url=$(cat url_info.txt)` does not work.

`lt --port 8080` would be kept running util encounter an error, then run and send another email again.

Not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Your command has no time to create the file before you try to read it. As a debugging aid or kludge, you can add `sleep 10` between the two operations to give it some time to create the file and write the URL

Comment: It actually worked! @thatotherguy would you please answer the question so that I can select you as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a race condition. `lt` starts writing a file and `cat` starts to read it, concurrently, at the same time.

- If `lt` manages to write something to the file first, then `cat` will read it.
- If `cat` is quicker, then it'll read the previous file or an empty file, depending on how far the `lt` has gotten.

The easiest hack is to add a `sleep 10` between them, to give `lt` a nice head start on writing the URL.

A more robust solution is reading output from `lt` until you get the information you want, but this would require knowing the expected output format of the command.